# Forcing non-www HTTPS from www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I've looked at several threads here, but it seems like no rules function if www is present. I've also tried to remove the www, and afterwards force HTTPS. Could be some minor typo that I don't understand htaccess well enough to find. I have contacted the hosting service in case there's a problem with the cert/web server.

What I want is for HTTPS to be forced also when a visitor writes www.domain.com in the addressbar.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Enable HSTS
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS

#Go to non-www if www
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Go to HTTPS it not already on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#check that filename is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#check that its a regular file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
#remove what comes after the dot from url
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#check that filename is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#check that its a regular file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
#remove what comes after the dot from url
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: By testing using: http://htaccess.mwl.be , it shows up that `http://www.ex.com` is redirected to `http://ex.com` & `http://ex.com` => `https://ex.com`

Comment: From my understanding it should work, but for some reason it does not. With the code in the .htaccess file, http://www.actionscript.no only looses the HTTP (possibly done by browser as it sees is as reduntant?). The www stays.

Comment: "no rules function if www is present." - does `www` resolve (CNAME set in DNS)? Do you see your site at all? (_Aside:_ If your goal is to redirect to HTTPS, then you should redirect to `https://` in your first `RewriteRule` as well - saves an additional redirect.)

Comment: "looses the HTTP (possibly done by browser as it sees is as reduntant?)" -  ??? The "http" is still there - that's just the browser _beautifying_ the URL that you see in the address bar. Chrome hides stuff like that and there is no option to display it. (Opera hides it by default, but you have the option to display the full URL. Although Opera will even hide the query string by default.)

Comment: I know that was poorly formulated by me(meant hidden/not shown), sorry. HTTPS was set in rule nr2 earlier, but removed due to debugging. Will fix. CNAME is set as www.actionscript.no > actionscript.no, so seems accurate to me. TTL is 14400, whereas I'm read that 3600 is good to use earlier. Not sure if that should have any effect on this though.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L] This should cover all non-HTTPS urls?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there was a .htaccess file both in root, as well as in public_html. I was using the one in root, unaware that there was a .htaccess in public_html.

Now the one in root is removed, and it all works perfectly! Thanks for all replies.